# SIGBUS crash on Solaris 8

Tags: z3

Compiled with g++ 4.7.4 on Solaris 8.  32 bit application.  Stack trace is

```
Core was generated by `./z3'.
Program terminated with signal 10, Bus error.
\#0  0x012656ec in vector&lt;unsigned long long, false, unsigned int&gt;::push_back (this=0x2336ef4 &lt;g_prime_generator&gt;, elem=@0xffbff1f0: 2) at ../src/util/vector.h:284
284             new (m_data + reinterpret_cast&lt;SZ *&gt;(m_data)[SIZE_IDX]) T(elem);
(gdb) bt
\#0  0x012656ec in vector<unsigned long long, false, unsigned int>::push_back (this=0x2336ef4 &lt;g_prime_generator&gt;, elem=@0xffbff1f0: 2) at ../src/util/vector.h:284
\#1  0x00ae66d4 in prime_generator::prime_generator (this=0x2336ef4 <g_prime_generator>) at ../src/util/prime_generator.cpp:24
\#2  0x00ae714c in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at ../src/util/prime_generator.cpp:99
\#3  0x00ae71c4 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_prime_generator.cpp(void) () at ../src/util/prime_generator.cpp:130
\#4  0x00b16a68 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
\#5  0x00b16aa0 in _init ()
\#6  0x00640b10 in _start ()
(gdb) list
279
280         void push_back(T const & elem) {
281             if (m_data == 0 || reinterpret_cast&lt;SZ *&gt;(m_data)[SIZE_IDX] == reinterpret_cast&lt;SZ *&gt;(m_data)[CAPACITY_IDX]) {
282                 expand_vector();
283             }
284             new (m_data + reinterpret_cast\&lt;Z *&gt;(m_data)[SIZE_IDX]) T(elem);
285             reinterpret_cast&lt;SZ *&gt;(m_data)[SIZE_IDX]++;
286         }
287
288         void insert(T const & elem) {
(gdb) ptype SZ
type = unsigned int
(gdb) ptype m_data
type = unsigned long long *
```

SIGBUS on Solaris is usually indicative of a misaligned access, but I am not sure if it is due to the casting going on an endianess issue

Comment: Is your processor SPARC64? You may have to modify the memory allocator to enforce 8-byte address alignment (regardless of whether you are using a 32-bit application) as Z3 doesn't know about any 64-bit CPUs that aren't AMD64.

Comment: I tried changing the memory alignment 8 bytes (in machine.h, bit shift is 3 instead of 2) and still get a SIGBUS in the exact same place.

Answer (score 0):

The SPARC data alignment requirements is most likely at issue.
The m_data field in the vector class is off by two fields that are used
to store the size and capacity of a vector. 
You can debug this by displaying (printing or using the debugger) the pointer m_data and it's alignment.

One option is to supply a separate vector implementation 
where the size and capacity fields are stored
in fields directly in the vector for porting this library utility.

Z3 interacts with memory alignment a few other places (but not overly many).
The main other potential places are in the watch lists (sat_solver and smt_context), and region memory allocators (region.h) and possibly in hash tables.

Comment: I did check on the m_data variable, and it is aligned on 4 bytes.  I did try making the memory aligned on 8 bytes, too, and got he same crash.  I will look into the other areas you pointed out, but from what I can in the code, it should be sufficient to change machine.h to align on 8 bytes, not 4.